# Snapping to Play Head in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In the Video Sequence Editor, how can I make a strip selection snap to the Play Head (the vertical blue cursor line)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select strips.
Right click to open menu.
Select Snap to Playhead.

[image]